# Python Exe is not running properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

I recently wrote a game in python using kivy and I wanted to turn it into an exe, only problem was when I used auto-py-to-exe to do that. It turned the project into an exe but when I tried to run the project the screen never came up or even ran. Which is weird because during development it worked with no issues what so ever.

To be more specific the gui framework I am using is kivy, and the commands I used where

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "E:/Trade/Server/md_5afec55eb036b.ico" --name "InvestIt" --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/server.db;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/routes.py;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/requirements.text;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/md_5afec55eb036b.ico;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/app_looks.py;." "E:/Trade/Server/server.py"
```

Comment: Can you give more detail, like the commands you used?

Comment: Does the script run without error when the `.py` file is run?

Comment: Yes the script ran without error when I used .py. Also the commands I choose where One directory, Windows, and then I just added my needed files

Comment: @LearnCode could you please be more specific with the commands you typed in ? The previous answer does not clarify what you did. Also is you code spread across multiple files or is it just one `.py` file ?

Comment: @TanishqVyas To be more specific the gui framework I am using is kivy, and the commands I used where pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "E:/Trade/Server/md_5afec55eb036b.ico" --name "InvestIt" --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/server.db;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/routes.py;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/requirements.text;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/md_5afec55eb036b.ico;." --add-data "E:/Trade/Server/app_looks.py;."  "E:/Trade/Server/server.py"